# Java create a folder in current package folder

Tags: java

In my java program, I want to write files to a folder inside my current package. If this folder doesn't exist, I will create it.

How do I refer to this maybe non-existent folder with relative path, so that if I move my package around, I don't have to manually fix the path?

```
private void writeFamilyPerFile(String name, ArrayList<String> planNames) {
    File file;
    File folder = new File(OUTPUT_DIR + "/temp/");
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        if(!folder.exists()) {
           folder.mkdir();
        }
        file = new File(folder + name + ".md");
        file.createNewFile();
        bw = new BufferedWriter(planNames);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`OUTPUT_DIR` is the path to my current package, and `folder` is the folder I want to create inside current package directory.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for answering my question. I'm not very experienced, so is making a lot mistakes.

I'm generating a bunch of markdown files, which could be used as is, and will be processed further later in my app, i.e., merged into 1 single file, and translated into HTML. My app lives inside a project, the file structure is like this:

```
root
  |--other parts
  |--definitions
  |    |--definition
  |    |--java
  |    |    |--validator
  |    |    |--docGenerator
  |    |--pom.xml
  |--pom.xml
```

**docGenerator** is my project. Where should I put:

- intermediate generated files, which I'd like to keep
- temp files I will generated, use and delete
- final output files
- resource files my program read and use

Big thanks to everyone!

Comment: What do you mean by "package"?  Do you mean a Java package?  Do you mean a project folder in your IDE?  A directory on your classpath, or in a JAR on your classpath? Something else?

Comment: package as, say the folder my java class files are inside, eg. `src/main/java/com.company.myPackage`

Comment: That's not a "package".  That is a folder within the your IDE's project folder.  Assuming that the folder is in the file system, it is a directory.

Comment: There may not *be* a 'current package directory'. Your application may be packaged into one or more JAR files. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming your current path is within the application folder (where your package folders are), and your class files are not within a jar, you can do this.

```
String OUTPUT_DIR = this.getClass().getCanonicalName().replace(".","/");
OUTPUT_DIR = OUTPUT_DIR.substring(0,OUTPUT_DIR.lastindexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear from your Question what you are trying to do.  However, I think that this is what you are asking for:

```
    ...
    File outputDir = new File(OUTPUT_DIR);
    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, planNames.get(i) + ".md");
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    ...
```

The above opens a file (named `planNames.get(i) + ".md"`) in the directory `OUTPUT_DIR`.  The file is opened for writing as a text file.  It will be created if it doesn't exist already, and truncated if it does exist.

This assumes that the output directory already exists, and that `OUTPUT_DIR` is a `String` whose value is a resolvable pathname for the directory.

---

I should also point out that writing files into the project source tree in your IDE is not going to work if your application even needs to run outside of an IDE.  (And this is a strange thing to do inside an IDE too ... unless you are generating *Java source code*.)

In that sense, you are probably *asking for* the wrong thing; i.e. something that doesn't make sense.  If you told us what you are actually trying to do here, we could suggest alternatives that made more sense.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my question to clarify my purpose.